# How to select the row (the team) in which the score column is the highest number, in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, max

In language R. Working with Data Frames.

The data frame is for keeping track of game scores for basketball. The rows represent different basketball teams. One of the columns represent overall score for the season.

How would I select the row (the team) that has highest score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `which.max()`:

```
set.seed(1) 
df = data.frame(team=letters[1:10],score=sample(1:10,10))
df[which.max(df$score),]
```

df:

```
   team score
1     a     3
2     b     4
3     c     5
4     d     7
5     e     2
6     f     8
7     g     9
8     h     6
9     i    10
10    j     1
```

Output:

```
  team score
9    i    10
```